# Prestashop Webservice Image Upload

Tags: php, web-services, curl, prestashop, crud

Hello and thanks in advance, now I'm trying to upload a image to a `prestashop 1.7` via webservice and I'm unable to insert a image in a product. I don't know what fails, because I don't get any response of the webservice, even with the debug enabled (I get the xml responses of the rest of the files, but not the ones from curl).

The variable `$idProduct` is a value passed to the function and is defined.

My code is the following:

```
$url = PS_SHOP_PATH."api/images/products/".$idProduct;
$dir_path_to_save = 'img/import/';

$img_path = getFile($remoteImageURL, $dir_path_to_save);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, PS_WS_AUTH_KEY.':');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => '@'.$img_path));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
echo print_r($response);
curl_close($ch);
```

The getFile function downloads the image to the server where is installed the prestashop and returns the path (returns a string with the real path where the image is stored, already tested).

I tried to make a form to upload the image (just for testing), but it returns `"code 66 - unable to save this image"`. I don't know if this helps.

Thanks

**UPDATE**

A fellow programmer told me to use `curl_file_create()`

So I changed the `$img_path` declaration this way:

```
$img = curl_file_create($dir_path_to_save.'/'.basename($img_path));
```

Now everything works as intended.